# nano 4.3 won't accept special characters, while nano 2.0.6 will

Tags: utf, nano

I can copy and paste UTF-8 etc. characters fine from a browser to a Mac terminal. I can also do this in nano version 2.0.6. See how it accepts the apostrophe from Chrome:

[image: nano 2.0.6 works]

The problem is that in nano 4.3, the paste fails because the apostrophe turns into gobbledegook: `^y

[image: nano 4.3 fails]

Ditto for other special characters such as double quotes etc., or other webpages or even other browsers such as Safari.

I have a Macbook Pro running MacOS Monterey 12.1 (latest). Any ideas what the issue with nano 4.3 is? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Happy to say that I resolved this, thanks to the kind folks at help-nano@gnu.org. I **upgraded to nano 6.0** and the issue disappeared.